# PHP To Show 2 Tables On One Page

Tags: php, html, joomla, html-table, joomla3.0

I am using this syntax to display a PHP Table on my page.  I now need to add in a second table directly above this one, but all the syntax I try throws a 500 error.  How can I with 1 connection to MSSQL run 2 Select statements and populate 2 individual html tables?

```
    $option = array();
$option['driver'] = 'mssql';
$option['host'] = 'IP Address';
$option['user'] = 'UserName';
$option['password'] = 'Password';
$option['database'] = 'DB';
$option['prefix'] = '';
$db = JDatabase::getInstance($option);
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query = "SELECT name, hiredate, bday, payrate, hourlypay from HRData ORDER BY name ASC";
$db->setQuery($query);
$query = $db->loadObjectList();
if ($query) 
{
    ?>
    <table border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Name </th>
    <th>Hire Date </th>
    <th>Birthday </th>
    <th>Pay Rate </th>
    <th>hourlypay </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
    foreach ($query as $res) 
    {
        print "<tr>";
        print "<td>" . $res->name . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . $res->hiredate . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . $res->bday . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . $res->payrate . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . $res->hourlypay . "</td>";
        print "</tr>";
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
This is the syntax I am trying to adapt, but I keep getting a 500 Error

```
    $option = array();
$option['driver'] = 'mssql';
$option['host'] = 'IP Address';
$option['user'] = 'UserName';
$option['password'] = 'Password';
$option['database'] = 'DB';
$option['prefix'] = '';
$db = JDatabase::getInstance($option);
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query = "SELECT name, MAX(Pay) As PayYTD FROM HRINFO";
$db->setQuery($query);
$query = $db->loadObjectList();
if ($query) 
{
    ?>
    <table border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Name </th>
    <th>YTD Pay </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
    foreach ($query as $res) 
    {
        print "<tr>";
        print "<td>" . $res->name . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . "$" . round($res->PayYTD) . "</td>";
        print "</tr>";
    }
}
<br><br><br>
//Query
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query = "SELECT name, hiredate, bday, payrate, hourlypay from HRData ORDER BY name ASC";
$db->setQuery($query);
$query = $db->loadObjectList();
if ($query) 
{
    ?>
    <table border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Name </th>
    <th>Hire Date </th>
    <th>Birthday </th>
    <th>Pay Rate </th>
    <th>hourlypay </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
    foreach ($query as $res) 
    {
        print "<tr>";
        print "<td>" . $res->name . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . $res->hiredate . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . $res->bday . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . $res->payrate . "</td>";
        print "<td>" . $res->hourlypay . "</td>";
        print "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: After this run next query as usual without closing the connection. It should work.

Comment: Do I use same variable $query?  like so $db = JDatabase::getInstance($option);
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

Comment: Yes you can use the same variable. Change the query and as usual you need to write these statements`$db->setQuery($query);` `$query = $db->loadObjectList();`

Comment: You seem to be confusing what setQuery and getQuery do with running an SQL statement directly. You should follow the syntax here: https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

Comment: @CodeIt -> see my edit, I am still getting a 500 error.

Comment: I see a syntax error:
    $query = "SELECT name, MAX(Pay) As PayYTD FROM HRINFO";
    ) AS A";

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh Please make edits properly. Why is that <br><br><br> in the code ? Remove or else echo it properly. Then try.

Comment: @CodeIt - I have that in there as I want to add in a few lines between the 1st table and the second table.

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh You can't just right plain html in php file. Either you have to echo it or print it like `echo "<br><br><br>";`. You are either not pasting the source code properly or editing source code after pasting.

Comment: @CodeIt you can put plain HTML in a PHP file, as long as you come out of PHP first by using a closing tag: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: That is what my issue was.  I needed to echo out the <br>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're having is that you are using the calls incorrectly.

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query = "SELECT name, MAX(Pay) As PayYTD FROM HRINFO";
$db->setQuery($query);
```

The first line will create an object, it doesn't matter which. The object will be in $query.

The second line will immediately destroy the object and assign a string to $query (this is incorrect).

The third line expects an object as a parameter to setQuery, but unfortunately it is a string! Error.

If you want this to work correctly, then you need to use the object in $query correctly.

I'm not a Joomla expert, so I link you to a page for how to do this correctly: https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

Answer (score -1):

Put the output in a variable.

```
$StringOut = '';
$StringOut .=     '<table border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Name </th>
    <th>Hire Date </th>
    <th>Birthday </th>
    <th>Pay Rate </th>
    <th>hourlypay </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>';

    foreach ($query as $res) 
    {
        $StringOut .=  "<tr>";
        $StringOut .=  "<td>" . $res->name . "</td>";
        $StringOut .=  "<td>" . $res->hiredate . "</td>";
        $StringOut .=  "<td>" . $res->bday . "</td>";
        $StringOut .=  "<td>" . $res->payrate . "</td>";
        $StringOut .=  "<td>" . $res->hourlypay . "</td>";
        $StringOut .=  "</tr>";
        }
$StringOut .=     '</table>';
#Do other logic to retrieve first table. 
#You could put it in a different variable if you like. And print when and whereever you wish.

echo $StringOut;
#Optionally close connection, done.
```

Comment: What? Why negative vote?
This is what the OP asked. A way to control output and print another table before the current one.